# thread::join() blocks when it shouldn't

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic, race-condition

To understand how to use atomics in C++11, I tried to following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

struct solution {
    atomic<bool> alive_;
    thread thread_;

    solution() : thread_([this] {
        alive_ = true;
        while (alive_);
    }) { }
    ~solution() {
        alive_ = false;
        thread_.join();
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr int N = 1; // or 2
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        solution s;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

If N equals 1, the output is `done`. However, if I set it to 2, the main thread blocks at thread::join(). Why do you think we don't see `done` when N > 1?

Note: If I use the following constructor:

```
    solution() : alive_(true), thread_([this] {
        while (alive_);
    }) { }
```

it prints `done` for any value of N.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't initialise `alive_` and only set it once the thread starts, the following interleaving of execution is possible:

```
MAIN: s::solution()
MAIN: s.thread_(/*your args*/)
MAIN: schedule(s.thread_) to run
thread: waiting to start
MAIN: s::~solution()
MAIN: s.alive_ = false
thread: alive_ = true
MAIN: s.thread_.join()
thread: while(alive_) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

`atomic<bool>` is, by default, initialized with false on Visual Studio (its initial value is undefined by standard).
So, the following sequence of events might happen:

1. A solution object is created, `alive_` is initialized to `false` and `thread_` is created (but not run).
2. The solution object is destroyed, the destructor runs and sets `alive_` to false, then waits for `thread_` to end (thread has not done anything)
3. `thread_` runs, sets `alive_` to true, and then loops forever (because the main thread is waiting for it to terminate).

Comment: @Angew wrote earlier so I marked his answer as correct.

Comment: `atomic<bool>` is not initialized with `false` by default: [atomics.types.generic]/5 requires atomics to have trivial default constructors. Note that Visual C++'s standard library implementation *does* value-initialize atomics, which is non-conforming.

Comment: @Casey interesting, you're right (29.5/5, which I would have appreciated if you mentioned). Anyway, this is only an even stronger argument for explicitly initializing the flag.

Comment: "data race" has a specific meaning in the standard. There is not one in this code.

Comment: @T.C. the main and worker threads are both writing to `alive_`, but the two writes are not in a happen-before ordering. In particular, `alive_=true` does not happen-before `alive_=false`, so the correctness of the program's behavior depends on the way the two writes interleave. Which I think conforms to the definition "The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other"

Comment: "at least one of which is not atomic". Both writes and all reads are atomic. A data race results in undefined behavior. This program's behavior is well-defined - it may terminate, it may loop forever, but it isn't allowed to make your cat pregnant.

Comment: @T.C.You're right. I'm stupid. I was lying in my bed when I realized it's an atomic bool, and got up again to apologize.